# Unable to determine the serialization information interface property of Mongo database entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm developing an application which is using Mongo database.
Right now, I'm having the class `Connection` as an entity:

```
public class Connection : DefaultEntity
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Setting of connection.
    /// </summary>
    public IConnectionSettings Settings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether connection auto start when application opens.
    /// </summary>
    public bool AutoStart { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Time when connection was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Time when connection was lastly modified.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTime { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public Connection(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Connection(Connection connection)
    {
        Id = connection.Id;
        Settings = connection.Settings;
        AutoStart = connection.AutoStart;
        CreatedTime = connection.CreatedTime;
        LastModifiedTime = connection.LastModifiedTime;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Base on an interface `IConnectionSettings`, I have the following implementations:

- TcpClientSettings:

```
public class TcpClientSettings : IConnectionSettings
{
    #region Properties

    public ConnectionKinds Kind => ConnectionKinds.TcpClient;

    /// <summary>
    /// TCP Client host name.
    /// </summary>
    public string HostName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// TCP Client port.
    /// </summary>
    public int Port { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether connection should be established automatically or manually.
    /// </summary>
    public bool AutoStart { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

- TcpListenerSettings

```
public class TcpListenerSettings : IConnectionSettings
{
    #region Properties

    public ConnectionKinds Kind => ConnectionKinds.TcpServer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Port to listen to the incoming connection.
    /// </summary>
    public int Port { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is how I setup my database collection:

```
services.AddScoped(options =>
{
    // Get mongo client.
    var mongoDatabase = options.GetService<IMongoDatabase>();
    var connections = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Connection>(MongoDatabaseCollectionNames.Connections);

    return connections;
});

BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(SerialPortSettings));
BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(TcpClientSettings));
BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(TcpListenerSettings));

if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Connection)))
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Connection>(options =>
    {
        options.AutoMap();
        options.MapCreator(x => new Connection(x.Id));
        options.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);

        options.MapProperty(x => x.Settings).SetIgnoreIfNull(true);
    });
}
```

The problem happens when I do a query like below:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddMongoDatabase(_connectionUrl, "smart-sensor");
_serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var connections = _serviceProvider.GetService<IMongoCollection<Connection>>();
var connectionFilterDefinition = Builders<Connection>.Filter
    .And(
        Builders<Connection>.Filter.Not(Builders<Connection>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Settings, null)),
        Builders<Connection>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Settings.Kind, ConnectionKinds.SerialPort)
    );

var loadedConnections = connections.Find(connectionFilterDefinition).ToList();
```

An exception happens:

[image]

It says: **Unable to determine the serialization information for x =>x.Settings.Kind**

My question is:

- How to fix the serialization/deserialization of `IConnectionSetting` interface.
- How to deserialize the interface property `Settings` in `Connection` base on `Settings.Kind` value. For example:
- If `Settings.Kind` = 1, deserialize the object to `TcpClientSettings`
- If `Settings.Kind` = 2, deserialize the object to `TcpListenerSettings`

Thank you,